# How to add Tags (Category_id) while creating customer (res.partner) in odoo?

Tags: ios, odoo, openerp-8, odoo-8

I am doing work on ODOO iOS application. 
I am creating Customer using `res.partner` model and with `create` method.
Customer is creating successfully without any error, but the tags field that I have selected during creation is not getting generated.

I have used below code for creating customer:

```
NSArray *inputParameter = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[userDic objectForKey:@"database"],[userDic objectForKey:@"userId"],[userDic objectForKey:@"password"],@"res.partner",@"create",customerDictionary,nil];

    // Show progress hud on main thread
    [[OpenERPGlobal appDelegate] showProgressHUD:@"Please wait" withView:self.view];

    // Depending on Id's read records
    WebService *service = [[WebService alloc] init];
    [service fetchDataWIthURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/xmlrpc/object",[userDic objectForKey:@"hostUrl"]]] withMethodName:ExecuteFunctionName withParameter:inputParameter withResult:^(id result,NSError *error)
     {
         [[OpenERPGlobal appDelegate] hideProgressHUD];

         if([result isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]])
         {
            [OpenERPGlobal showMessage:@"Customer created successfully." delegate:self tag:10 cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
         }
     }
```

And the input parameter for above call is as below:

```
{
    "category_id" =     (
        17,
        10,
        9,
        13
    );
    city = California;
    email = "sample@gmail.com";
    fax = "";
    function = "";
    "is_company" = 0;
    mobile = "";
    name = "123 Sample Customer";
    phone = "";
    street = "Street address";
    website = "http://www.sample.com";
}
```

In above input parameter `category_id` is my key for tags.

Does anybody has faced this kind of issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In *res_partner* object *category_id* has many2many relationship. So you need to add using *[6, 0, [ids]]*

Try this values:

```
{
    "category_id" = [(6, 0, [17, 10, 9, 13])],
    city = California;
    email = "sample@gmail.com";
    fax = "";
    function = "";
    "is_company" = 0;
    mobile = "";
    name = "123 Sample Customer";
    phone = "";
    street = "Street address";
    website = "http://www.sample.com";
}
```

[For more details of Many2one, One2many and Many2many field](https://doc.odoo.com/v6.0/developer/2_5_Objects_Fields_Methods/methods.html#osv.osv.osv.write)

Comment: Thank you very much Odedra... I am facing this issue from previous 2 days. You rocks.

Comment: @Odedra what do the `6` and `0` in `"category_id" = [(6, 0, [17, 10, 9, 13])],` represent? Without explanation, they seem rather arbitrary to a noob. Is there documentation one can reference explaining this?

Comment: @MichaelMügge You are correct. I should include brief description of it. You may refer updated answer link.

Comment: @Odedra, does this also work when adding a new record for a model that `_inherits` from res.partner or do you have to add your record first, then get the `partner_id` and add the relationship to the res.partner model?

Comment: Yes It will work. But make sure id must have registered into database.